# On unprotecting (expanding) \protected macros (or, "the space after command name")

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion, debugging

I quite often come into a situation, where I need to obtain some text produced by a package macro as a string, like in say:

- [Expanding (edef) a lipsum command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26806/expanding-edef-a-lipsum-command)
- [How do I "unprotect" an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48825/how-do-i-unprotect-an-argument)

One thing I bump into here, is trying to `\typeout` the macros in question, and typically observing a space between the `\command` and its arguments (hence the title); and I'd usually take this wrongly as a string parsing problem (*as in, how do I remove the space between the command and its arguments*), and spend quite a bit of time in a pointless battle `:)`

---

EDIT: to clarify this:

- In the 1<sup>st</sup> link: `\lipsum[1]` command typesets "Lorem Ipsum..." in the PDF document; one would want to somehow obtain the characters for "Lorem Ipsum..." in a `\temp` command, such that `\typeout{\temp}` would print "Lorem Ipsum ..." to the terminal and log output.
- In the 2<sup>nd</sup> link: `\today` from `isodate` typesets "24 May, 2012" in the PDF document; likewise, one would want to somehow obtain the characters for "24 May, 2012" in a `\temp` command, such that `\typeout{\temp}` would print "24 May, 2012" to the terminal and log output.

(whether `\edef` is used for the purpose is not that much of an issue, I guess; but as far as I can see, it is the only command possibly appropriate)

---

Now, I finally came up with an MWE that demonstrates this, so I'd like to ask about this in more generic terms - consider:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\def\doubleCommand#1#2{testing-#1-#2}

\protected\def\tmpcmd#1{teststring#1} % concatenate, no spaces


\begin{document}

\typeout{--Test:--\doubleCommand{A}{B}--}

\edef\initArg{12}
\edef\dcArg{\tmpcmd\initArg}

\typeout{--Args:--\initArg--\dcArg--}

\edef\myResult{\doubleCommand{\dcArg}{Verbatim}}
\edef\myResult{\detokenize\expandafter{\myResult}}

\typeout{--Out :--\myResult--}

This: \doubleCommand{\dcArg}{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Now, this works fine, and typesets "`This: testing-teststring12-Verbatim`", as expected. However, if we look at the terminal log output from `pdflatex`, we get:

```
--Test:--testing-A-B--
--Args:--12--\tmpcmd 12--
--Out :--testing-\tmpcmd 12-Verbatim--
```

That is, the `\edef` didn't expand the `\tmpcmd` command - and its name is printed instead, along with the arguments (*and notably, there is the space between the command and the first argument `:)`*).

However, since the content is typeset fine, it is obviously accesible somewhere - and it is this content that I would like to have as a "string" in a variable. To show this, all I need to do is remove the `\protected` command, so I have:

```
\def\tmpcmd#1{teststring#1} % concatenate, no spaces
```

... and then the terminal log shows:

```
--Test:--testing-A-B--
--Args:--12--teststring12--
--Out :--testing-teststring12-Verbatim--
```

... that is, the command output ("`teststring12-Verbatim`") is now a "string" value in a "variable" (command).

Now, I'm pretty sure there are good reasons for `\protected`; however, many times I just want to get to the data which is typeset anyways. So is there a strategy that one could employ in these cases? The above links suggest there is not, and a solution - if possible - depends on a given package's command, and its implementation... However, I'd like a method that I could employ, without changing package style files (*like, say, removing `\protected` from diverse macros I might need, which even without further knowledge, I can tell is a bad idea*).

I can already guess such a general method is not available - but could anyone explain why (maybe in terms of the above MWE)?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something here: `\protected` macros are used precisely because the do not expand inside `\edef` or similar. That's usually because they contain material which will fail to `\edef` correctly. Are you creating these macros, are are they from 'somewhere else'. If the later, it might be useful to say where.

Comment: @JosephWright - currently I'm trying to capture (using `\edef`) the return of a `\citefield` (or `\printfield`) in biblatex, from a `\newbibmacro` hook; the items typeset at the spot where I want them as command contents, but because of the `\protected` I cannot capture them. However, I've met this in other contexts as well, which is why I'd like to have a better understanding of this generally. Cheers!

Comment: Also, maybe it's expressed in these terms: if commands are protected so I cannot get their contents in say, `\typeout` - how come those very same contents are typeset in the document, if I just issue the command normally at the very same spot in the code?

Comment: Notice that `\protect` and `\protected` are *very* different beasts and mustn't be confused with each other. The protection of commands with optional arguments or defined via `\DeclareRobustCommand` doesn't rely on `\protected`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

David has explained this one way, I will take a slightly different tack.

First, what is going on? When e-TeX finds a protected macro, it will not expand it inside an `\edef`, `\write` and some similar circumstances, which usually exhaustively expand everything. That is to ensure you can see the protected *token* in the result. For example,

```
\protected\def\a{}
\typeout{%
  \a%
  b%
}
```

will show `\a b`, even though there is no space between `\a` and `b` as far as TeX is concerned. That's because the alternative is `\ab`, which as we can't see the tokens would be misleading (does it mean `\a` followed by `b` or a different macro `\ab`?).

You can 'force' expansion of a protected macro by using the fact that they do respect `\expandafter`:

```
\protected\def\a{b}
\edef\test{\expandafter\empty\a}
\show\a
```

using `\empty` as something to expand after which will not result in anything remaining behind.

Second, why do you need protection? Some operations in TeX simply will not work within an `\edef` as they use TeX primitives which are not 'expandable'. The classic ones here are assignments (`\def`, `\let` and so on). If you try

```
\let\a\undefined
\def\b{a}
\edef\test{\let\a\b}
```

you will not find that `\a` ends up defined to give `a`. Instead, you'll get an error: in this case '`Undefined control sequence`'. That is because `\let` is not expandable. So TeX simply 'leaves it alone' inside the `\edef`, and tries to expand `\a`. That's not possible, and so an error arises. Thus in general it is not a good idea to try to expand protected macros.

Comment: Many thanks for clearing up (my) mystery of the space after command name, @JosephWright! `:)` Thanks for the `\empty` trick; I note that using it as `\edef\test{\expandafter\empty\today}` on `isodate`'s `\today`, will crash with `! Undefined control sequence. \equal..`, so I wouldn't be able to get to the "May 24, 2012" as characters anyways. Good example on the need for `\protected` too - moved accept here; cheers!

Comment: @sdaau `\today` with `isodate` is not protected nor robust. The problem there is that after two steps of expansions it presents TeX with `\ifthenelse`, which wants to perform assignments that are *not* executed in an `\edef`.

Comment: Many thanks for that clarification, @egreg - cheers!

Answer (score 13):

`\protected` stops expansion in `\edef` and `\write` and (unlike the LaTeX protection mechanism) it's not so easy to take off once it is applied.  It's a bit hard to know what you need here as you ask for the "string" but TeX doesn't have strings.

you can do

```
\makeatletter

\protected\def\foo#1{---{\large#1}---}


\edef\x{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\foo}
\show\x
```

which produces

```
> \x=macro:
->---{\large #1}---.
l.8 \show\x
```

but note here that `\x` does *not* contain the `\large` command in its definition, it has the 6 tokens `\ l a r g e` (plus other tokens`---{}---`).

To see *why* you need protection, compare

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\foo#1{---{\large#1}---}


\edef\x{\foo 1}
\show\x
```

putting a fragile unprotected command in an edef produces

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@nomath ...e \@font@warning {Command \noexpand #1
                                                  invalid in math mode}\fi 
l.8 \edef\x{\foo 1
                  }
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Fantastic, @DavidCarlisle - many thanks for that! It both explains how to get to some of these contents (and what is the problem with that); and why `\protected` is needed in the first place. I'm still kinda bugged that I can, say, get the `\today` typeset; but at the same instance in the doc, I cannot get "Thu 24 May"  as (expanded) characters in a command I'd use elsewhere (_that would be the "string" or "variable value"; with "string" I just try to point out part of my misunderstanding could be due C/OOP approach_). But at least I have a good reference now for this - thanks again; cheers!