# Expandable author names from biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, expansion

Knowing that `\printnames` command in `biblatex` is not expandable as it is protected, and I [cannot otherwise do much about it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57229/on-unprotecting-expanding-protected-macros-or-the-space-after-command-name); I thought about going through `biblatex.sty` and reconstructing `\printnames` with unprotected commands - in hope that I can get an expandable version.

Note that while `\printfield{FIELD}` is not expandable, `\thefield{FIELD}` is (*and it simply calls commands of the type `\abx@field@FIELD`*) - so I don't have that much problem with "plain" fields. However, for names, one needs to declare a name format, and then one needs to iterate through a list (*which ultimately uses `\abx@name@FIELD`*), so it's more complicated.

This is MWE of how far I got - still not working:

```
\documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{trace}

  \usepackage{filecontents}
  \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @misc{num01,
      title = {Title1},
      author = {Author1 Authorsen1 and Author1a Authorsen1a},
      howpublished = {12-23-2001},
      eprint = {MR001},
      eprinttype = {mrnumber}}
  @misc{num02,
      title = {Title},
      author = {Author2},
      howpublished = {12-23-2002},
      eprint = {002},
      eprinttype = {mrnumber}}
  @misc{num03,
      title = {Title XX3},
      author = {Author2 Authorsen2 and Author2a Authorsen2a},
      howpublished = {12-23-2003},
      eprint = {MR003 (aa)},
      eprinttype = {mrnumber}}
  @misc{num04,
      title = {Title},
      author = {Author4},
      howpublished = {12-23-2004},
      eprint = {004 (bb)},
      eprinttype = {mrnumber}}
  \end{filecontents}

  \usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
  \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
  abbreviate=false,%
  uniquename=allfull,%
  maxnames=99,%
  minnames=99,%
  backend=biber,%
  }
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

  \DeclareNameFormat{testauthors}{% now only this works
  \iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}
  }%

  % copy of printnames:
  \makeatletter
  \def\getAuthsX{
  %   \let\@tempc\relax % no effect
    %
    \blx@getformat\blx@theformat{nfd}{testauthors}{author} %
    \blx@begunit
    \blx@namesetup{1}{99}{author}% {#2}{#3}{#4} - start, stop, 'namelist'
    \expandafter\blx@nameparser\blx@thedata{}&%
    \blx@endunit
  }
  \def\getAuths{\blx@listargs\getAuthsX}
  \makeatother

  % just a test for usual field: 
  \DeclareFieldFormat{myentrykey}{%
    Testing #1 %
  }

  \newbibmacro*{myentrycite}{% custom
  \printfield[myentrykey]{entrykey}
  } % end \newbibmacro*{

  \DeclareCiteCommand{\myentrycite}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
     \printtext{\usebibmacro{myentrycite}}}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}

  \myentrycite{num03}

  \getAuths

\end{document}
```

I would ultimately like to use something like `\edef\mytemp{\getAuths}`; but for now, I'm just testing if it will work in a typesetting context. Building this with:

```
pdflatex test.tex
biber test
pdflatex test.tex
```

... and the `\getAuths` function breaks here:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \@tempc 
\KV@split ...efix \@tempa \endcsname \ifx \@tempc 
                                                  \relax \KV@errx {\@tempa \...

\KV@do ...lax #1\empty \else \KV@split #1==\relax 
                                                  \expandafter \KV@do \fi 
\setkeys ...{KV@#1@}\let \@tempc \relax \KV@do #2,
                                                  \relax ,
\blx@nameparser@i ...{\setkeys {blx@opt@name}{#1}}
                                                  \blx@theformat 
<argument> ...rt \else \blx@nameparser@i \ifblank 
                                                  \fi \advance \c@listcount ...

\@secondoftwo #1#2->#2

\getAuthsX ...dafter \blx@nameparser \blx@thedata 
                                                  {}&\blx@endunit 
\reserved@c ->\getAuthsX 
                         {}{}{}
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

As far as I can see, it complains about `\@tempc` - but even me setting `\let\@tempc\relax` explicitly before the run doesn't help (*not to mention that, it should already be set to `\relax` in `\setkeys`, if I read that stack trace correctly*)

If one insists with pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> for the run to complete, the output in the PDF of `\getAuths` is something like:

```
,1 and ∆ ’ ¿ and ’ ¿
```

.... which (seemingly) means the author names loop has been run - but obviously, not the right data is retrieved.

Could anyone confirm if this is possible to do - and if so, explain what am I missing to have it work?

<sub>Is it that `\let` is not expandable? But what does it matter here in this example then, as I'm not yet calling `\edef` ?!</sub>

---

EDIT:

Ok, the first problem was an oversight of mine - calling something like `\thefield{FIELD}` implies there is a "current" bib item being processed - and having `\getAuths` called from the body of the document does not set any specific bib item.

So the solution to that, is simply have `\getAuths` be called from a command that selects a specific bibliography entry, such as `\myentrycite{num03}` (*I knew there was a reason I kept all that code there `:)`*).

So with the following change in above example:

```
  ....
  \DeclareFieldFormat{myentrykey}{%
    Testing #1 \getAuthsX  %
    \edef\tmpa{\getAuthsX}
  }
  ...
\begin{document}

  \myentrycite{num03}

\end{document}
```

... one can see the author names of entry `num03` typeset in the PDF document, which was the starting intent (*and one can just use the `\getAuthsX` directly*).

However, I still cannot get the expansion (as in `\edef\tmpa{\getAuthsX}` to work), so I'd appreciate any pointers there...

Comment: `\let` is indeed not expandable, nor other macro definitions are...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Expandable macros can be defined from unformatted bibliographic data. The `\savename` command simply copies an unformatted name list to a macro. These data can also be accessed via formatting directives defined with `\DeclareNameFormat` or `\DeclareIndexNameFormat`.

`\DeclareIndexNameFormat` is intended to write data to the index, but we can use it to pick up data from each name in the list. Inside its resulting directive, `biber`-only name delimiters (e.g. `\bibinitperiod`) expand to plain text. This is useful because `biblatex` punctuation commands are only defined within citation or bibliography commands.

The document below demonstrates a formatting directive `getname` that appends the first names (`#3`) (or first initials (`#4`) under the `firstinits=true` option setting), last name prefix (`#5`) and last name (`#1`) to the expandable macro `\name`. The directive is executed by the `\getauthor` citation command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,firstinits]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\name}{}
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{getname}{%
  \def\addcomma{,}
  \def\space{ }
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}
    {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
       {\xappto{\name}{\addcomma\space}}
       {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}
          {\xappto{\name}{\finalandcomma}}
          {}%
        \xappto{\name}{\space\bibxstring{and}\space}}}
    {}%
  \ifblank{#4}   % See update below
    {}
    {\iffirstinits
       {\xappto{\name}{#4\space}}
       {\xappto{\name}{#3\space}}}%
  \ifblank{#5}
    {\xappto{\name}{#1}}
    {\xappto{\name}{#5\space#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\getauthor}
  {\undef\name
   \boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\ifnameundef{author}
     {}
     {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifnumgreater{\value{citecount}}{1}}
                   and not test {\ifundef{\name}} }
        {\gappto{\name}{; }}
        {}%
      \indexnames[getname][1-99]{author}}}
  {}
  {}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\getauthor{knuth:ct,vangennep}
\edef\temp{Some text \name}
\subsubsection*{\temp}
\getauthor{companion,aristotle:anima,ctan}
\subsubsection*{\MakeUppercase{\name}}
\textcite{cms,companion,aristotle:anima,ctan}
\end{document}
```

---

**UPDATE** Since the original answer the syntax of `\DeclareIndexNameFormat` has changed: instead of arguments #1 to #8 the full name is stored in #1 and can be accessed by different `\namepart` macros. The affected part of the code above works with the following changes:

```
\nameparts{#1}
\ifblank{\namepartgiveni}
  {}
  {\iffirstinits
     {\xappto{\name}{\namepartgiveni\space}}
     {\xappto{\name}{\namepartgiven\space}}}%
\ifblank{\namepartprefix}
  {\xappto{\name}{\namepartfamily}}
  {\xappto{\name}{\namepartprefix\space\namepartfamily}}}
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, shiver me timbers! Getting this done was a PAIN!!

@Audrey already answered an hour ago, however, I also got to a solution in the meantime, so I'd just like to document it here...

To begin with - the most important part for me - here is the terminal output of the (not so) MWE, posted at end:

```
(./test.aux) (./test.bbl)
taA__Authorsen1__A.\spacefactor \blx@sf@dot ______
taB__Authorsen1__Author1______
ta --Author1 Authorsen1==
taA__Authorsen1a__A.\spacefactor \blx@sf@dot ______
taB__Authorsen1a__Author1a______
ta -- and Author1a Authorsen1a.==

= currentauthors =
==Author1 Authorsen1 and Author1a Authorsen1a.==

taA__Authorson2__A.\spacefactor \blx@sf@dot ______
taB__Authorson2__Author2______
ta --Author2 Authorson2.==

= currentauthors =
==Author2 Authorson2.==

taA__Authorsen3__A.\spacefactor \blx@sf@dot ______
taB__Authorsen3__Author3______
ta --Author3 Authorsen3==
taA__Authorsen3A__A.\spacefactor \blx@sf@dot ______
taB__Authorsen3A__Author3A______
ta --, Author3A Authorsen3A==
taA__Authorsen3B__A.\spacefactor \blx@sf@dot ______
taB__Authorsen3B__Author3B______
ta --, and Author3B Authorsen3B.==

= currentauthors =
==Author3 Authorsen3, Author3A Authorsen3A, and Author3B Authorsen3B.==


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 407--408
```

Names seem to be properly expanded as 'plain text'; however, the example also shows that this approach can still coexist with the usual `biblatex` typesetting:

[image: test.png]

(<sub>*the main intent of the expandable process is simply to provide text characters; however in the MWE it also typesets (though not succesfully) simply as an example - otherwise, only a single command should be commented to suppress the typeset output, see code*</sub>)

### Discussion

A few words, while I can still remember... Basically, it was all spinning in circles and looking at endless `traceon` outputs, until one realizes that the `\DeclareNameFormat` is the main part where one could have those names at all; then by accident I tried to wrap an `\edef` over its inner macros:

```
%   \DeclareNameFormat{testauthors}{% now only this works
%   \typeout{ta==#1==#4==#5==#7==}
%   \typeout{ta==#1==#3==#5==#7==}
%   \edef\tmpa{
%   \iffirstinits
%     {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
%     {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
%   \usebibmacro{name:andothers}
%   }
%   \typeout{ta--\tmpa==}
%   \tmpa
%   }%
```

... and while that failed - it also sparked the idea to wrap only the `\usebibmacro`s in separate `\edef` (which is the basis of the current solution):

```
%   \DeclareNameFormat{testauthors}{% now only this works
%   \typeout{ta==#1==#4==#5==#7==}
%   \typeout{ta==#1==#3==#5==#7==}
%   
%   \iffirstinits
%     {\edef\tmpa{\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}}
%     {\edef\tmpa{\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}%
%   \usebibmacro{name:andothers}
%   
%   \typeout{ta--\tmpa==}
%   \tmpa
%   }%
```

That didn't work very well either - but at least it started showing which commands are the unexpandable ones; so I could redefine them in my .tex file as unprotected commands. So again by a long process of `trace`ing, I started copying existing functions from `biblatex.sty` into my `.tex` file. This part is again not trivial - because not all functions can be found defined verbatim in `biblatex.sty`; then one can use either `\show` in the .tex document itself - or `texdef` (*usually when a definition is not shown with one method, it will be shown with one of the other two*).

Then, one should keep in mind that a protected `biblatex` command like `\usebibmacro{name:first-last}` has an "internal" counterpart in `\abx@macro@name:delim` (*and I still cannot tell how I figured out the proper relationships, apart from staring in logs and source files `:)`*) But the internal commands could be protected as well - or if not, may make use of protected macros; so it takes a while to identify a "minimal" set of "hacked" definitions that are needed.

Another thing to keep in mind is that `\DeclareNamesFormat` will be called for *each individual name* in a citation; therefore, one cannot expect to "pull" a complete "names list" in one pass - in the MWE below, there is a "global" "variable" (`\currentauthors`), which is used to concatenate the contents generated in each pass - and should contain the complete author name list as expanded text, once the custom cite process is finished.

Also, I should note that wherever I could, I tried removing typesetting commands like `\unhbox` and such, as they are typically also non-expandable; there seems to be some calculation for interpunction in `biblatex` based on diverse skips - but their removal doesn't seem to have too much effect on the expanded names list.

I got to a critical point when I got this log output:

```
taA==Authorsen2==A.======
taB==Authorsen2==Author2======
ta --Author2 Authorsen2 ==
taA==Authorsen2a==A.======
taB==Authorsen2a==Author2a======
ta --\ifboolexpr {test {0}ortest 0}{, }{ and }Author2a Authorsen2a ==
```

... that meant that almost all I needed was expanded - except for a `\ifboolexpr`. First I thought of using `boolexpr` package, but that conflicts with etoolbox/biblatex ... Then it turns out that there is an expandable `\ifboolexpe` in `etoolbox` as well - and once that got replaced, I could in fact remove some superfluous redefinitions.

Once the whole thing started generating decent names (the rules `biblatex` uses to compose names lists seem to be preserved, also for the expanded text output), there was another problem: since I basically redefined "core" macros of `biblatex`, now I could have a custom cite which is expandable - but the "usual" non-expandable custom cite wouldn't work anymore!

That got solved by adding the prefix `EX` to all redefined macro names, to help distinguish them from the default ones - and that seems to allow for a mix of methods, that allow both usual typesetting of author names via `biblatex`; and also allow for expansion of the same.

Well, I guess that was all I could remember `:)` However, there are plenty of comments in the code - so hope it helps someone..

### MWE Code

(build w/ `pdflatex test.tex` ; `biber test` ; `pdflatex test.tex`)

```
\documentclass{book}

  \usepackage{trace}

  \usepackage{filecontents}
  \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @misc{num01,
      title = {Title1},
      author = {Author1 Authorsen1 and Author1a Authorsen1a},
      howpublished = {12-23-2001},
      eprint = {MR001},
      eprinttype = {mrnumber}}
  @misc{num02,
      title = {Title},
      author = {Author2 Authorson2},
      howpublished = {12-23-2002},
      eprint = {002},
      eprinttype = {mrnumber}}
  @misc{num03,
      title = {Title XX3},
      author = {Author3 Authorsen3 and Author3A Authorsen3A and Author3B Authorsen3B},
      howpublished = {12-23-2003},
      eprint = {MR003 (aa)},
      eprinttype = {mrnumber}}
  @misc{num04,
      title = {Title},
      author = {Author4},
      howpublished = {12-23-2004},
      eprint = {004 (bb)},
      eprinttype = {mrnumber}}
  \end{filecontents}

  \usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
  \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
    abbreviate=false,%
    uniquename=allfull,%
    maxnames=99,%
    minnames=99,%
    backend=biber,%
  }
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

  %\usepackage{boolexpr} %tlmgr install boolexpr ; expandable? yes, but:
  % overwrites the \ifboolexpr by etoolbox (loaded by biblatex),
  % and then everything breaks.. so cannot use


  \makeatletter


  % must keep, else appears as unexpanded in output
  % was \protected ; used \isdot
  %
  % (biid): dot in mathmode;
  %         \mathchardef\blx@sf@dot=1002;
  %         1002 abbreviation period (dot)
  %         typesetting related ?! don't use, it doesn't expand
  %         doesn't run in this example (we don't typeset anymore)?
  %         but it can kick in, if \abx@dot gets added here after fi
  %
  \def\EXblx@imc@isdot{%
  \ifnum\blx@spacefactor=\blx@sf@period
    %\spacefactor%                    (rtc)
    \blx@sf@dot %                     (biid)
  \fi
  }

  % must keep, to remove unexpanded typesettin cmds
  %
  \def\EXabx@dot{%
  \ifdim\lastkern>\z@\unkern\fi
  .%
  %\spacefactor%                      (rtc)
  %\blx@sf@dot%                       (rtc)
  }%

  % must keep, to remove unexpanded \unspace
  %
  \def\EXblx@addpunct#1{%
  %\unspace%                          (rtc)
  \ifnum\blx@spacefactor<\blx@sf@threshold@low
    \csuse{blx@qp@#1}\csuse{abx@#1}%
  \else
    \ifnum\blx@spacefactor>\blx@sf@threshold@high
      \csuse{blx@qp@#1}\csuse{abx@#1}%
    \else
      \ifcsdef{blx@pp@\the\csname blx@sf@#1\endcsname} %
        {\csuse{blx@qp@#1}\csuse{abx@#1}}
        {\csuse{blx@qp@#1}}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \csuse{blx@pq@#1}}

  % must keep, else appears as unexpanded in output
  % was \protected ; used \adddot
  %
  \def\EXblx@imc@adddot{%
  \EXblx@addpunct{dot}%
  \ifnum\blx@spacefactor=\blx@sf@period
    %\spacefactor%                    (rtc)
    %\blx@sf@dot%                     (rtc)
  \fi}

  % must keep, else "! Undefined control sequence."
  % was \protected ; used \addcomma
  %
  \def\blx@imc@addcomma{%
    \EXblx@addpunct{comma}}

  % was \newrobustcmd* ; used \adddot
  %
  \def\bibinitperiod{\EXblx@imc@adddot} %  ;

  % must keep, else appears as unexpanded in output
  % was \protected
  %
  \def\EXblx@imc@resetpunctfont{%
  \blx@ifpuncthook
    {\global\let\abx@puncthook\@firstofone}
    {}}

  % (rtc) removed typesetting cmd

  % must keep, else appears as unexpanded in output
  % was \newrobustcmd
  %
  \def\EXaddlowpenspace{%
  %\unspace%                          (rtc)
  \blx@postpunct%
  %\penalty\value{lownamepenalty}%    (rtc)
  \space%
  \EXblx@imc@resetpunctfont}

  % must keep, else appears as unexpanded in output
  % was \newrobustcmd
  %
  \def\EXbibnamedelimd{\EXaddlowpenspace} %

  % must keep, else appears as unexpanded in output
  %  was \protected
  %
  \def\EXaddspace{%
  %\unspace%    %                     (rtc)
  \blx@postpunct%
  \space%
  \EXblx@imc@resetpunctfont%
  }

  % leaving \def\finalnamedelim out would cause trouble;
  %  even if by default it if not protected..
  %  that is because here, we want to avoid use of
  %  protected \bibstring => instead, \blx@imc@bibxstring
  %
  \def\EXfinalnamedelim{% not protected - for ref..
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}%
  {\finalandcomma}%
  {}%
  \EXaddspace%
  \blx@imc@bibxstring{and}%\bibstring{and}%
  \space%
  }

  \def\EXlbx@finalnamedelim#1{%
    \EXfinalnamedelim%
  }


  % redef without long -- now namebreak no complain:
  %
  % if this \def for namebreak is commented,
  % then starting to get in console:
  % "### semi simple group (level 3) entered at line 333 (\begingroup)"
  %
  % but must now re-define it along w/ nameparser, to allow
  % interface with normal work
  %
  \def\EXblx@namebreak#1&{}

  \def\EXblx@nameparser#1{%
    \ifblank{#1}
      {\EXblx@namebreak\relax}
      {\ifnum\c@listcount<\c@liststart
       \else
         \EXblx@nameparser@i#1%
       \fi
       \advance\c@listcount\@ne
       \ifnum\c@listcount>\c@liststop
         \expandafter\EXblx@namebreak
       \fi
       \EXblx@nameparser}}

  \def\EXblx@nameparser@i#1{%
    \ifblank{#1}
      {}
      {\setkeys{blx@opt@name}{#1}}% this
    \blx@theformat}

  % also had previously redefined here:
  %   \DeclareRobustCommand{\KV@prefix}{}
  %   \def\blx@namesetup@i#1{%
  %   \def\blx@namesetup@ii#1#2{%
  %   \def\blx@namecodes{%
  %   \def\blx@namesetup#1#2#3{%

  % originally, here \ifboolexpr was used;
  %  when used in expandable context; \ifboolexpr will fail with
  %  "! Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }" - UNLESS
  %  default paths (like {True}{False} for \ifnumless;
  %  and \ifmorenames must have one char only, {1}{0}) are added!
  %  only then, not getting the \@secondoftwo problem!
  % BUT: \ifboolexpr robust = \ifboolexpe expandable
  % if using \ifboolexpe - then should NOT have the added T/F branches!
  %
  \expandafter\def\csname EXabx@macro@name:delim\endcsname#1{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}%
    {\ifboolexpe{%
        test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}%
        or%
        test {\ifmorenames}%% \blx@imc@ifmorenames
      }%
      {\multinamedelim}{\EXlbx@finalnamedelim{#1}}%
    }%
    {}%
    %\show\bibstring%\typeout{==name:delim==#1==}% bibstring=\protected macro:
  }


  % (nfl1): MUST have comment after cmd here; else a spurious space
  %         appears at end of last name! also removed \blx@imc@isdot (typeset)
  % (nfl2): added: hack to "hardcode" a dot after all of the names are done
  % (nfl3): \ifmorenames -> \blx@imc@ifmorenames
  %
  \expandafter\def\csname EXabx@macro@name:first-last\endcsname#1#2#3#4{%
    \csname EXabx@macro@name:delim\endcsname{#2#3#1}%
    \csname abx@macro@name:hook\endcsname{#2#3#1}%
    \ifblank{#2}%
    {}%
    {\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\EXblx@imc@isdot\EXbibnamedelimd}%
    \ifblank{#3}%
    {}%
    {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\EXblx@imc@isdot%
      \ifpunctmark{'}{}{%
        \ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\EXbibnamedelimd}}%
    }%
    \mkbibnamelast{#1}\EXblx@imc@isdot%
    \ifblank{#4}{}%
    {\EXbibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}}%  (nfl1)
    \ifboolexpe{%                         (nfl2)
        test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}%
        or%
        test {\ifmorenames}%              (nfl3)
      }%
      {}{\EXabx@dot}%
  }


  % (dnf1): expanding name:andothers is currently a problem;
  %          fails w/ "! Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }."
  %          but, 'and' in names gets added automatically - without name:andothers;
  %          name:andothers just if we want it shortened ("and others").
  %          and I don't need that currently..
  % (dnf2): perform concatenation here;
  % (dnf3): this "return" output of \tmpa also typesets;
  %          comment it out if typeset not desired
  %
  \DeclareNameFormat{testauthors}{%
    \typeout{taA__#1__#4__#5__#7__}
    \typeout{taB__#1__#3__#5__#7__}
    %\traceon
    \iffirstinits%
      {\edef\tmpa{\csname EXabx@macro@name:first-last\endcsname{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}}%
      {\edef\tmpa{\csname EXabx@macro@name:first-last\endcsname{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}%
    %\edef\tmpb{\csname abx@macro@name:andothers\endcsname } % (dnf1)
    \csname abx@macro@name:andothers\endcsname

    \typeout{ta --\tmpa==}
    \global\edef\currentauthors{\currentauthors\tmpa} % (dnf2)
    \tmpa %                                             (dnf3)
  }%


  %\blx@namesetup: {#2}{#3}{#4} - start, stop, 'namelist';
  %            eg. {1}{99}{author} - but can do without
  %
  \def\getAuthsX{%
    \blx@getformat\blx@theformat{nfd}{testauthors}{author}%
    \blx@namesetup{}{}{author}%
    \expandafter\EXblx@nameparser\blx@thedata{}&%
  }

  \makeatother


  \def\getAuths{%
    \getAuthsX%
  }

  \newbibmacro*{myentrycite}{% custom
    \global\def\currentauthors{} % init empty string for concat
    \getAuths
  }

  \DeclareCiteCommand{\myentrycite}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{myentrycite}}
    {}
    {}

  %%%%%%%%%%%%

  \DeclareNameFormat{normauthors}{%
  \iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}
  }%

  \newbibmacro*{normentrycite}{% custom
    \printnames[normauthors]{author}%
  }

  \DeclareCiteCommand{\normentrycite}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{normentrycite}}
    {}
    {}


\begin{document}

  %\traceon

  \textit{Author names output of expandable cite commands:}

  % adding new cites will require a new biber run!
  \myentrycite{num01}
  \typeout{^^J= currentauthors =^^J==\currentauthors==^^J}

  \myentrycite{num02}
  \typeout{^^J= currentauthors =^^J==\currentauthors==^^J}

  \myentrycite{num03}
  \typeout{^^J= currentauthors =^^J==\currentauthors==^^J}

  \bigskip

  \textit{Author names output of usual cite command:} \\

  % will give "Runaway argument?" if all
  % defaults are reprogrammed; and not
  % handled with separate names!
  \normentrycite{num03}

\end{document}
```