# How can I make \citetitle work in a hyperref section bookmark?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, bookmarks

I'm trying to use `hyperref` on a very large number of section headings for pieces of artwork in a document, but I have to use a workaround to get the title of the artwork into a bookmark of the section:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTWORK{gizapyramid,
  title = {Pyramids at Gizeh},
  year = {ca.\@ 2500 BCE}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{\texorpdfstring%
{\citetitle{gizapyramid} (\citedate{gizapyramid})}%
{Pyramids at Gizeh}}

\end{document}
```

Doing that properly displays "Pyramids at Gizeh" in the bookmark; however, since I occasionally find myself tweaking the title of various artworks to more accurately match common names, I would like to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTWORK{gizapyramid,
  title = {Pyramids at Gizeh},
  year = {ca.\@ 2500 BCE}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{\texorpdfstring%
{\citetitle{gizapyramid} (\citedate{gizapyramid})}%
{\citetitle{gizapyramid}}}

\end{document}
```

The problem with that is it throws the warning:

> Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string
>   (PDFDocEncoding): (hyperref) removing `\citetitle' on input line 20.

Then, it displays the tag "gizapyramid" in the bookmark instead of "Pyramids at Gizeh" as desired.

How can I make `\citetitle` work in a `hyperref` section bookmark like I want without ruining its normal behavior elsewhere in the document?

Comment: Basically you can't. The bookmarks accepts essentially only strings of characters, not the instructions needed to produce them.

Comment: @egreg Would it not be possible to somehow define a string variable from an evaluation of the instructions, then pass that onto the bookmark?

Comment: @Gnintendo That is possible, but the string macro must be expandable. To ensure this, you need to access unformatted data via an indexing or formatting directive. Heiko's answer is good for fields. For names, see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60552/4483.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can profit of my [**`usebib`** package](https://ctan.org/pkg/usebib):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTWORK{gizapyramid,
  title = {Pyramids at Gizeh},
  year = {ca.\@ 2500 BCE}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{usebib}
\bibinput{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\section{\texorpdfstring%
{\citetitle{gizapyramid} (\citedate{gizapyramid})}%
{\usebibentry{gizapyramid}{title}}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Bookmark strings need to be converted to PDF strings. The main step is expanding the string to get rid of the TeX/LaTeX commands. However many commands do not work in expandable contexts. Some left "garbage" that is filtered out by `\pdfstringdef` or some undesired stuff remains in the bookmark or the macro even breaks.

The `\cite...` commands of `biblatex` will not work in expandable contexts and are not supported in bookmarks. They are even protected macros (by e-TeX's `\protected`). That makes it easy to filter them out and give a proper warning.

As workaround, the title can be extracted outside the bookmarks and stored in a macro that is used in the bookmarks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTWORK{gizapyramid,
  title = {Pyramids at Gizeh},
  year = {ca.\@ 2500 BCE}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\StoreCiteField}[3]{%
  \begingroup
    \global\let\StoreCiteField@Result\relax
    \citefield{#2}[StoreCiteField]{#3}%
  \endgroup
  \let#1\StoreCiteField@Result
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{StoreCiteField}{%
  \gdef\StoreCiteField@Result{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\StoreCiteField\TitleGizapyramid{gizapyramid}{title}
\section{\texorpdfstring
{\citetitle{gizapyramid} (\citedate{gizapyramid})}%
{\TitleGizapyramid}}

\end{document}
```

I have used a detour via a formatting command to get the data. Are there side effects of `\citefield` that should be taken care of? Do better ways exist?

Comment: +1: Could this be expanded (as a separate question) so that it works with `author`? `\citefield{key}{author}` is nor possible with biblatex (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207591).

Comment: NVM, I was able to use: `\newcommand*{\StoreAuthor}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \global\let\StoreAuthor@Result\relax
    \citeauthor{#2}%
  \endgroup
  \let#1\StoreAuthor@Result
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{StoreAuthor}{%
  \gdef\StoreAuthor@Result{#1}%
}`

Comment: Aaahh! This is the kind of thing I was looking for ... :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I can't figure it out for the author case, though. The code you've given doesn't seem to use the `StoreAuthor` format you define?

Comment: @cfr Great to see you again! I did that at my office (work laptop). I can check on Monday.

Comment: @cfr Would that be ok or too late?

Comment: @cfr I also have a follow-up question, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634795.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thank-you! No, not too late at all. No rush. I've been meaning to look at this for well over a year so I don't think Monday is too late! I've just let bibkeys go in bookmarks. I have since found something that works in simple cases using `\citename{#1}[StoreAuthor]{author}` and then defines `\DeclareNameFormat{StoreAuthor}{%   
  \xdef\StoreAuthor@Result{\ifdefvoid\namepartprefix{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}\namepartfamily\ifdefvoid\namepartsuffix{}{\comma\space\namepartsuffix}}%
}`. I hoped to piggy-back on `labelname` but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: @cfr That is similar for me, for now, I also use the key in the bookmark because a proper solution is much harder than expected. But if I remember correctly, then I made an MWE work. Feel free to provide your code as an answer to my question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634795). That will be helpful to continue the effort.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner i put it in chat for now because it is really ... er ... early? simple-minded? But if you think it would be useful after actually seeing it, I'll post it there. (I did consider that but it just seemed too crappy.) I've even got an MWE for it because I wanted something quicker than a real document.

Comment: @cfr Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637962.