Include Annotation in Bibliography
I would like to include the abstract of a reference as an annotation in the bibliography. Instead of the actual abstract, it only writes "abstract".
\documentclass[
a4paper,12pt,
]{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
    \printfield{title}\pdfcomment{{\printfield{abstract}}}%
}

\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{my.bib}
    @article{einstein05,
        author={Albert Einstein},
        title={Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper},
        abstract={Interesting article, which claims that time is relative.},
        journal={Annalen der Physik und Chemie},
        volume={17},
        year={1905},
        pages={891--921}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{my.bib}
\begin{document}
    The principles of the Special Relativity Theory were first published in
    1905\cite{einstein05}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}



Have a look at the terminal output or log file. hyperref tells you what the problem is. (This is not the same as solving it, but it is a necessary first step.)

Thanks, this seems to be the problem:
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\printfield' on input line 32.

Yes. I have code which gets the contents of bib fields into hyperlnks (e.g. author into bookmarks etc.). However, I'm not sure it will work for pdfcomment. I'm not sure pdfcomment works correctly for me even in the case of regular text. (If so, the result is ghastly, but I'm guessing it isn't so.)

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73690/. (This isn't a duplicate, but it is related.)

Your main problem here is that \pdfcomment needs expandable input, but \printfield is a command to print the field contents and is highly non-expandable. For simple fields, you can obtain the field contents expandably with \thefield. \pdfcomment{\thefield{abstract}} works here.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}%
  \iffieldundef{abstract}
    {}
    {\pdfcomment{\thefield{abstract}}}}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein05,
  author={Albert Einstein},
  title={Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper},
  abstract={Interesting article, which claims that time is relative.},
  journal={Annalen der Physik und Chemie},
  volume={17},
  year={1905},
  pages={891--921}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
  The principles of the Special Relativity Theory were first published in
  1905\cite{einstein05}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}


