# Full cite of cross-referenced entry

Tags: biblatex, biber, expansion

I have an entry key `foo` in my (biblatex-biber managed) bibliography, with a `crossref` field pointing to another entry key.
To automate type-setting operations on a series of files, I would like to be able to cite the cross-referenced entry with something like:
`\citefull{\citefield{foo}{crossref}}`

This naive syntax does not work, as biblatex commands are not nestable/expandable.
Any hints on how to proceed?

Bonus, that could be handy too:
`\citefull[\citefield{foo}{note}]{\citefield{foo}{crossref}}`

What I've tried:
Many posts mention this nesting/expanding limitation and propose a workaround. I thus know this is somehow *possible*, but I don't understand the codes well enough to adapt them to my needs. For example [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267297/how-can-i-print-the-equivalent-of-textcite-in-the-bibliography-for-a-cross-re) seems quit closely related. The closest that I got was tweaking [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60633), which is supposed to be *more* complex that what I need, as it deals with name list and I only want to expand a monolithic field. My tweak below does print the full reference of key `num3` when calling key `num4` (whose `author` field contains `num3`) like I want it to. However, I was not able to call the `crossref` field (nor a custom `verba` field) instead of the `author` field.

```
\documentclass{article}                                                      
\usepackage[american]{babel}                                                 
\usepackage[backend=biber,firstinits]{biblatex}                              

\usepackage{filecontents}                                                    
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}                                           
@misc{num03,                                                                 
title = {Title XX3},                                                         
author = {Author2 Authorsen2 and Author2a Authorsen2a},                      
}                                                                            
@misc{num04,                                                                 
title = {Title},                                                             
author = {num03},                                                            
verba = {num03},                                                             
crossref = {num03},                                                          
}                                                                            
\end{filecontents}                                                           
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}                                                

\newcommand*{\name}{}                                                        
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{getname}{%                                           
\nameparts{#1}                                                               
\ifblank{\namepartgiveni}                                                    
  {}                                                                         
  {\iffirstinits                                                             
     {\xappto{\name}{\namepartgiveni\space}}                                 
     {\xappto{\name}{\namepartgiven\space}}}%                                
\ifblank{\namepartprefix}                                                    
  {\xappto{\name}{\namepartfamily}}                                          
  {\xappto{\name}{\namepartprefix\space\namepartfamily}}}                    
\DeclareCiteCommand{\getauthor}                                              
  {\undef\name                                                               
   \boolfalse{citetracker}%                                                  
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}                                                  
  {\ifnameundef{author}                                                      
     {}                                                                      
     {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifnumgreater{\value{citecount}}{1}}                
                   and not test {\ifundef{\name}} }                          
        {\gappto{\name}{; }}                                                 
        {}%                                                                  
      \indexnames[getname][1-99]{author}}}                                   
  {}                                                                         
  {}                                                                         

\begin{document}                                                             
\getauthor{num04}                                                            
\fullcite{\name}                                                             
\end{document}
```

Which, after the correct pdflatex/biber runs, gives:
[image: result]

I also have another (ugly) workaround based on an `execute` field containing a `\nocite{num03}`. I then tweak `printbilbiography` and it *kind of* goes the way I need... But it really doesn't sound like a proper way of doing this!

Comment: Could you please add an example (with your already existing entries) what you want to see in the end?

Comment: I've edited the post to include the output of the example I give. It already gives what I want to get in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way entry data is saved in `biblatex` means we can't expandably get hold of field values (which is a bit of a bummer), so we will have to work with helper macros that hold the field value.

```
\makeatletter
% {<command>}{<entrykey>}{<field>}
\newcommand*{\getfieldinto}[3]{%
  \nocite{#2}%
  \begingroup
  \blx@getdata@cite{#2}%
  \edef\my@tempa{\endgroup
    \def\unexpanded{#1}{%
      \blx@imc@iffieldundef{#3}
        {}
        {\csexpandonce{abx@field@#3}}}}%
  \my@tempa}
\makeatother
```

Works similar to the code in the question that extracts the name expandably, but works on a field level and is less complicated, because it does not have to deal with the complexities of name handling in `biblatex`.

```
\getfieldinto{<command>}{<entrykey>}{<field>}
```

extracts the contents of `<field>` for `<entrykey>` into the macro `<command>`. So you would use it like

```
\getfieldinto{\mycomm}{num04}{verba}
```

to get `num04`'s `verba` into `\mycomm`.

The fields `crossref` and `xref` that one might intuitive want to use here can't be used because they are special and may not actually make it to the `.bbl` file (the entry data read by `biblatex`), so something like `verba` (or a custom `verb` field) is probably the safest option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, giveninits]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
% {<command>}{<entrykey>}{<field>}
\newcommand*{\getfieldinto}[3]{%
  \nocite{#2}%
  \begingroup
  \blx@getdata@cite{#2}%
  \edef\my@tempa{\endgroup
    \def\unexpanded{#1}{%
      \blx@imc@iffieldundef{#3}
        {}
        {\csexpandonce{abx@field@#3}}}}%
  \my@tempa}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{num03,
  title  = {Title XX3},
  author = {Author2 Authorsen2 and Author2a Authorsen2a},
}
@misc{num04,
  title    = {Title},
  verba    = {num03},
  note     = {note},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\getfieldinto{\mykey}{num04}{verba}
\getfieldinto{\mynote}{num04}{note}
\fullcite[\mynote]{\mykey}
\end{document}
```

[image: Expected output.]

It is possible to access the entry data of a different entry from within a cite command, so there may well be a way to solve your problem differently (and possibly more elegantly), but for that we would have to know what your actual use case is about.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to up-vote your very didactic answer... Thanks a lot anyway! I'll accept it as soon I've checked it works all right, and whether I need to edit my question/post a new one.

Comment: Well, it does the job and +1 for providing a generic mean to expand any field, that will definitely be useful. I'm slightly disappointed that I have to repeat the cross-reference key in `verba` but never mind, it's far better that my previous hacks!

Comment: @letax In principle you could get the `crossref` field to show in the `.bbl` at all times by setting `mincrossrefs=1,` (the default is `mincrossrefs=2,`), but that has side-effects if you ever really want to use `crossref` for their intended function. (You can also use a sourcemap to copy `crossref` to `verba` automatically. Then you only need the code for the sourcemap and need not copy the fields manually.)

Comment: Sounds great to automate this! From the doc p197 I tried `\DeclareSourcemap{\maps[datatype=biblatex]{\map{\step[fieldsource = crossref] \step[fieldset = verba] }}}` which compiles ok but does not work... Should I ask a new question or edit this one?

Comment: @letax You're missing an `origfieldval` and you can combine the two `\step`s into one: `\DeclareSourcemap{\maps[datatype=bibtex]{\map{\step[fieldsource = crossref, fieldset = verba, origfieldval]}}}`.

Comment: @letax A slightly shorter alternative would be `fieldtarget`, then we don't need the `origfieldval`: `\DeclareSourcemap{\maps[datatype=bibtex]{\map{\step[fieldsource = crossref, fieldtarget = verba]}}}`

Comment: this works well on the mwe, not in my full document. Working with multiple `*bib` seems to have no impact... Investigating.

Comment: @letax In case you need to ask more about that I suggest you ask a new question and don't edit this question here.

Comment: Dumb-old-classical typo... It works perfectly. Thanks again for your help, I learned a lot today!