# \newrobustcmd not expandable as key-value?

Tags: macros, expansion, etoolbox

I do some TeX experiments with 'postponed' content, writing it to some file to be included later on (not necessarily at end, but most time it would be appropriate to place it there)

I defined some writing command `\WriteSomeContent` with optional parameters, again using the `xkeyval` interface.

All is a test so far, as such I write a `\pdfbookmark` and a bookmark color to the postponed file. If there is no explicitly stated `bookmarkcolor=colorname`, it should default to `\BookmarkDefaultColor`, which is a command created by `\newcommand`.

Everything works as long one does not change from

```
\newcommand{\BookmarkDefaultColor}{red}%
```

to

```
\newrobustcmd{\BookmarkDefaultColor}{red}%
```

This leads to a statement `\BookmarkDefaultColor` with a final whitespace character, confusing `color=\BookmarkDefaultColor` and stopping the compilation.

Is this a bug of `\newrobustcmd` in conjunction with keyvalue expansion or some strange non-gobbling of a whitespace character (which should not be there at all, in my opinion)???

`**postponed.tex**`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{blindtext}%

\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}


\newcommand{\BookmarkDefaultColor}{red}%
%\newrobustcmd{\BookmarkDefaultColor}{red}%


\makeatletter
\define@key{FamilyA}{bookmarkcolor}[\BookmarkDefaultColor]{%
\def\KVMacroColor{#1}%
}%


\makeatother

\presetkeys{FamilyA}{bookmarkcolor=\BookmarkDefaultColor}{}%



\newcommand{\WriteSomeContent}[4][]{%
\setkeys{FamilyA}{#1}%
\immediate\write\myhandle{%
\string#4% Content first
\string\phantomsection%
\string\pdfbookmark[1,color=\KVMacroColor]{#2}{#3}% Some bookmark
}% End of \immediate\write
}% End of command



\newwrite\myhandle%


\AtBeginDocument{%
\immediate\openout\myhandle=\jobname.post%
}%

\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\closeout\myhandle%
\IfFileExists{\jobname.post}{\input{\jobname.post}}{Sorry, no file there}%
}%


\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\WriteSomeContent[bookmarkcolor={cyan}]{Entry 3}{entry::number::3}{\expandafter\unexpanded{\chapter{This is the 3rd one!}}}%

\WriteSomeContent{Entry 1}{entry::number::1}{\expandafter{\unexpanded{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{\blindtext}}}% 
}% End of unexpanded
}%

\WriteSomeContent[bookmarkcolor={blue}]{Entry 2}{entry::number::2}{\expandafter{\unexpanded{%
\vspace{\baselineskip}%

\noindent\large\textbf{And now for something completely different:}\normalsize\

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\noindent
\textbf{\textcolor{brown}{%
\blindtext}}}}}%

\chapter{Second}%



\end{document}
```

Temporarily written **`postponed.post`**

```
\expandafter\chapter {This is the 3rd one!}\phantomsection\pdfbookmark[1,color=cyan]{Entry 3}{entry::number::3}
\expandafter{\textbf {\textcolor {blue}{\blindtext }}}\phantomsection\pdfbookmark[1,color=\BookmarkDefaultColor ]{Entry 1}{entry::number::1}
\expandafter{\vspace {\baselineskip }\par \noindent \large \textbf {And now for something completely different:}\normalsize \^^M\par \vspace {\baselineskip } \noindent \textbf {\textcolor {brown}{\blindtext }}}\phantomsection\pdfbookmark[1,color=blue]{Entry 2}{entry::number::2}
```

And some output of the programme:

Please do not frown on `chapter 3` occurring before chapter 1` etc. All is done on purpose and belongs to a more widespread framework, it will be *cured* at the right time.

[image]

Comment: One of the purposes of `\newrobustcmd` is not to expand the defined command in a `\write`.

Comment: @egreg: Really????I found no statement about the non-expansion in the manual or does `robust` imply this?

Comment: `\newrobustcmd` is syntactic sugar for `\protected\def`.

Comment: @egreg: I should have looked into the `*.sty` file then `;-)`, shouldn't I?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Did you read the `etoolbox` manual :-) _Since it uses e-TeX’s low-level protection mechanism ..._

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Read the bottom of page 14 in `texdoc etex`

Comment: @JosephWright,@egreg: I see that I have still a lot to learn about the core of `TeX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When TeX does a `\write`, it fully expands material in the same way as `\edef` does. Thus

```
\immediate\write\myhandle{%
  \string#4% Content first
  \string\phantomsection%
  \string\pdfbookmark[1,color=\KVMacroColor]{#2}{#3}% Some bookmark
}%
```

causes `\KVMacroColor` to be expanded 'as far as possible'. If you insert

```
\show\KVMacroColor
```

just before the above lines you'll see three lots of  output

```
> \KVMacroColor=macro:
->cyan.

> \KVMacroColor=macro:
->\BookmarkDefaultColor 

> \KVMacroColor=macro:
->blue.
```

where the key one is that middle case. When `\BookmarkDefaultColor` is defined using `\newcommand`, it's a normal macro is is itself expandable. Thus TeX happily converts it to it's content as part of the `\write`. On the other hand, when you use `\newrobustcmd` you are creating an e-TeX *protected macro*: these do *not* expand inside `\edef`-like contexts. TeX therefore writes the name of the command into the output. The space appears because TeX adds it in: after every control word a space is added so that the tokenization will be correct on reading back. The usual demo for the need for that is something like

```
\catcode`\q=12 %
\protected\def\foo{bar}
\immediate\write\mywrite{\fooq}
```

Note that I'm writing *two* tokens to the file: `\foo` and `q`, and they should be read back in the same way, which the added space ensures. (You see exactly the same in lots of places: `\def\foo{\bar\baz}` then `\show\foo` and see the spaces!)

Comment: See _e.g._ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57229/on-unprotecting-expanding-protected-macros-or-the-space-after-command-name for more on protected commands