# Correct way to compare macro definitions that contain protected macros, e.g., bibnamedelima

Tags: biblatex, comparison, protected-macro

I'm trying to compare the content of `\partnamefamily` of an author's name in `biblatex` against a manual definition that is stored in another macro, lets call it `\family`, using `\ifdefequal`.

So, I have

- `Lastname` is found without problem in the comparison
- `Compound~Lastname` creates a problem as the `~` is converted to a `\bibnamedelima` macro that is stored inside. So the name is `Compound\bibnamedelima Lastname` instead. And that is not the same when doing the definition comparison.

The issue, that I think is happening, is related to the protected macro `\bibnamedelima` that appears when the name has a non-breaking space (`~`). If the name has no special delimiter that is handled by `biblatex` the comparison works fine. However, I can't compare it when that happens. My solutions were

- Try to expand it, and then compare strings or macros with the expanded `\partnamefamily` on it. But didn't work. I guess it is due to the protected macro `\bibnamedelima`.
- Try to compare the macros by doing a substitution, but that didn't work either.

I searched for a way of expanding macros with protected macros on it (like [On unprotecting (expanding) \protected macros (or, "the space after command name")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57229/on-unprotecting-expanding-protected-macros-or-the-space-after-command-name) and [Expanding arguments before macro call](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104506/expanding-arguments-before-macro-call)) but didn't help. Also, tried to convert it to string without success.

**Is there a way to compare these two macros directly?**

Here is an example to show my problem

```
% !BIB program = biber
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{identifier1,
  Title                    = {Some Awesome Title},
  Author                   = {One~Two, Author and Three, Author},
  Booktitle                = {Some Book about the Future},
  Year                     = {2042},
  Pages                    = {1--42}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newcommand*{\name}[1]{%
  \def\lastname{#1}}
\name{}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  % I have a complex expression here, so I was using the \ifboolexpr
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefequal{\lastname}{\namepartfamily}} }
  {(F)\mkbibbold{#1}}{(NF)#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\name{One~Two}% not found due to ~, as biblatex convert ~ to \bibnamedelima
\printbibliography
\name{One\bibnamedelima Two}% found due to \bibnamedelima instead of ~
\printbibliography
% found as it is not using any delim
\name{Three}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to hear that, but the nicest way to compare names in `biblatex` (in my opinion) is to use hashes [as hinted at by Audrey here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73246/35864) and [explained in one of my answers here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274571/35864).

Comment: I saw the hashes, but wanted to have something more readable and easy to use on the text. Is there a way to produce the hash of a given name on the fly? Didn't find info on this. So, I was looking for some trick of expanding the name all the way through the `\bibnamedelima` and putting it back into a macro, or something in that lines.

Comment: Since Biber produces the hashes I'm not aware of a solution where it is calculated on the fly from within the document. If you insist on comparing namer parts, maybe you need to temporarily redefine all `\bibnamedelim...`s and do the comparison on expanded macros... But I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily redefine `\bibnamedelima` and `~` to a simple space.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\bibnamedelima{ }%
    \def~{ }%
    \edef\adn@tmp@lastname{\lastname}%
    \edef\adn@tmp@namepartfamily{\namepartfamily}%
    % I have a complex expression here, so I was using the \ifboolexpr
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcsequal{adn@tmp@lastname}{adn@tmp@namepartfamily}} }
      {(F)\mkbibbold{#1}}
      {(NF)#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

In particular you can now use the easier to digest

```
\name{One Two}
```

This is similar to [Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey)'s answer to [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73246/35864), the answer there takes care of more of `biblatex`'s delimiters, but the general idea is the same.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{identifier1,
  Title                    = {Some Awesome Title},
  Author                   = {One~Two, Author and Three, Author},
  Booktitle                = {Some Book about the Future},
  Year                     = {2042},
  Pages                    = {1--42}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newcommand*{\name}[1]{%
  \def\lastname{#1}}
\name{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\bibnamedelima{ }%
    \def~{ }%
    \edef\adn@tmp@lastname{\lastname}%
    \edef\adn@tmp@namepartfamily{\namepartfamily}%
    % I have a complex expression here, so I was using the \ifboolexpr
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcsequal{adn@tmp@lastname}{adn@tmp@namepartfamily}} }
      {(F)\mkbibbold{#1}}
      {(NF)#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\name{One~Two}
\printbibliography

\name{One\bibnamedelima Two}
\printbibliography

\name{One Two}
\printbibliography

\name{Three}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]