# xparse: \NewDocumentCommand using a set of predefined keys

Tags: exam, xparse, l3keys

I would like to understand what makes the following not work, and how to fix it in order to get the desired output as given under each call of the command `\myQFormat`.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[xparse]{tcolorbox}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\NewTColorBox{MarksTCBox} { O{} }{
    left skip= 0pt,
    right skip=0pt,
    left=2pt,
    right=2pt,
    capture=hbox,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    nobeforeafter,
    box align = base,
    baseline=4pt,
    #1
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { Qoptions }
{
    label       .tl_set:N  = \l__Qoptions_label_tl,
    label       .initial:n = Question,
    sublabel    .tl_set:N  = \l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl,
}

\cs_new:Npn \Question_header:n #1
{
    \qformat{
        \textbf{
            \underline{
                \large \tl_if_blank:nTF {\l__Qoptions_label_tl} { Question } { \l__Qoptions_label_tl }~
                (\thequestion)\ \IfValueT{\l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl}{[\l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl]\ }
                \begin{MarksTCBox}
                    \scan_stop: [\totalpoints\ Marks]
                \end{MarksTCBox}
            }
        }
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \myQFormat } { O{} }
{
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { Qoptions } { #1 }
    \Question_header:n { #1 }
    \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}

        \myQFormat
        \question[15]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
        The output should be ``Question 1 [15 Marks]''

        \myQFormat[label = Part]
        \question[10]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
        The output should be ``Part 2 [10 Marks]''

        \myQFormat[label=Part, sublabel=Subtitle]
        \question[5]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
        The output should be ``Part 3 [Subtitle] [5 Marks]''

        \myQFormat[sublabel=Subtitle]
        \question[10]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
        The output should be ``Question 4 [Subtitle] [10 Marks]''

    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problems are:

- `\tl_if_blank:nTF` expects a braced “normal argument” (`n` type) directly containing the tokens to test, such as `\tl_if_blank:nTF { abc~def } { true } { false }` or, if we are in a macro definition and argument `#1` is a token list, `\tl_if_blank:nTF {#1} { true } { false }`. But what you want to test here is the *contents (value) of a token list variable*. For this, you need `\tl_if_blank:VTF` (the `V` causes the *value* of the first argument to be passed to the base form `\tl_if_blank:nTF`). Example:

  ```latex
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l__my_var_tl { true } { false }
  ```
- When your `\myQFormat` has been fully executed, its `\group_end:` has restored the two token list variables `\l__Qoptions_label_tl` and `\l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl` to the values they had before the group started, i.e., empty here. So, when `\question` uses these variables as part of the question format, they are both empty.

For the second point, the following code calls `\keys_set:nn` inside the argument of `\qformat`. This allows you to use the names `\l__Qoptions_label_tl` and `\l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl` in the format definition. I'll show another possible approach below.

As egreg noted, the `\tl_if_blank:...` test for the label is not really needed, since the initial value of `\l__Qoptions_label_tl` is set with `label .initial:n = { Question }` (the braces may be omitted since there is no comma in `Question`). The only case where this test would be useful is if you want to obtain “Question” as the label when using the option `label=` or even `label={ }` (indeed, “blank” means ”empty or spaces only” in this context, therefore if you pass an argument containing only space tokens, `\tl_if_blank:nTF` will execute the “true” branch).

```latex
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[xparse]{tcolorbox}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\NewTColorBox{MarksTCBox} { O{} }{
    left skip= 0pt,
    right skip=0pt,
    left=2pt,
    right=2pt,
    capture=hbox,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    nobeforeafter,
    box align = base,
    baseline=4pt,
    #1,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { Qoptions }
  {
    label       .tl_set:N  = \l__Qoptions_label_tl,
    label       .initial:n = { Question },
    sublabel    .tl_set:N  = \l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl,
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \Qoptions_question_header:n #1
  {
    \qformat
      {
        % \question appears to create a group, so the options are duly cleared
        % when the question title has been typeset.
        \keys_set:nn { Qoptions } {#1}
        \textbf
          {
            \underline
              {
                \large
                % Possible but not really needed (see above):
                % \tl_if_blank:VTF \l__Qoptions_label_tl { Question }
                %   { \l__Qoptions_label_tl }
                \tl_use:N \l__Qoptions_label_tl
                \nobreakspace \thequestion \
                \tl_if_blank:VF \l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl
                  { [ \l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl ] \ }
                \begin{MarksTCBox}
                    \scan_stop: [\totalpoints\ Marks]
                \end{MarksTCBox}
              }
          }
          \hfill % Otherwise, you'll have an Underfull \hbox for each question.
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \myQFormat } { O{} }
  {
    \Qoptions_question_header:n {#1}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}

    \myQFormat
    \question[15]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
    The output should be ``Question 1 [15 Marks]''

    \myQFormat[label = Part]
    \question[10]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
    The output should be ``Part 2 [10 Marks]''

    \myQFormat[label=Part, sublabel=Subtitle]
    \question[5]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
    The output should be ``Part 3 [Subtitle] [5 Marks]''

    \myQFormat[sublabel=Subtitle]
    \question[10]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
    The output should be ``Question 4 [Subtitle] [10 Marks]''

  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Other approach

Another way to avoid the problem due to the values of `\l__Qoptions_label_tl` and `\l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl` being restored too early (before `\question` uses them) is as follows. You can pass the *values* of `\l__Qoptions_label_tl` and `\l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl` to `\Qoptions_question_header:n` using a `V` argument type. Since you have two “normal arguments” to pass, the function now has to be named `\Qoptions_question_header:nn` and accept two arguments `#1` and `#2` (the label and sublabel). You can then use `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \Qoptions_question_header:nn { VV }` to create the needed function variant (namely, `\Qoptions_question_header:VV`), and call `\Qoptions_question_header:VV \l__Qoptions_label_tl \l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl` in `\myQFormat` to pass the *values* of `\l__Qoptions_label_tl` and `\l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl` to `\Qoptions_question_header:nn`.

```latex
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[xparse]{tcolorbox}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\NewTColorBox{MarksTCBox} { O{} }{
    left skip= 0pt,
    right skip=0pt,
    left=2pt,
    right=2pt,
    capture=hbox,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    nobeforeafter,
    box align = base,
    baseline=4pt,
    #1,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { Qoptions }
  {
    label       .tl_set:N  = \l__Qoptions_label_tl,
    label       .initial:n = { Question },
    sublabel    .tl_set:N  = \l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl,
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \Qoptions_question_header:nn #1#2
  {
    \qformat
      {
        \textbf
          {
            \underline
              {
                \large
                % Possible but not really needed (see above):
                % \tl_if_blank:nTF {#1} { Question } {#1}
                #1 \nobreakspace \thequestion \
                \tl_if_blank:nF {#2} { [ #2 ] \ }
                \begin{MarksTCBox}
                    \scan_stop: [\totalpoints\ Marks]
                \end{MarksTCBox}
              }
          }
          \hfill % Otherwise, you'll have an Underfull \hbox for each question.
      }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \Qoptions_question_header:nn { VV }

\NewDocumentCommand { \myQFormat } { O{} }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { Qoptions } {#1}
    \Qoptions_question_header:VV \l__Qoptions_label_tl \l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl
    \group_end:
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}

    \myQFormat
    \question[15]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
    The output should be ``Question 1 [15 Marks]''

    \myQFormat[label = Part]
    \question[10]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
    The output should be ``Part 2 [10 Marks]''

    \myQFormat[label=Part, sublabel=Subtitle]
    \question[5]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
    The output should be ``Part 3 [Subtitle] [5 Marks]''

    \myQFormat[sublabel=Subtitle]
    \question[10]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
    The output should be ``Question 4 [Subtitle] [10 Marks]''

  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Same output as above.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification. I have some inquiries if you don't mind: `1-` does setting an initial value of `label` make sense or redundant when I have this line `\tl_if_blank:VTF \l__Qoptions_label_tl { Question }
                  { \l__Qoptions_label_tl }` ? `2-` what does `\cs_new_protected:Npn` mean?  I mean its description in words like _this is a function that accepts one input braced argument and uses it internally without braces_. I tried to take a look at expl3 manual but it is not that friendly.

Comment: 1) Yes, just try replacing `label .initial:n = { Question }` with `label .initial:n = { XXX }` and you'll see the difference. This defines `\l__Qoptions_label_tl` at the earliest place (when `\keys_define:nn { Qoptions } {...}` is executed). It is used when the `label` option is not passed to `\myQFormat`. 2) `\cs_new_protected:Npn` is similar to `\protected\long\def`, but in `expl3` style, and errors out if the function is already defined. It is one of the ways to define a code-level function (as opposed to document-level ones defined with `xparse`'s `\NewDocumentCommand` and friends).

Comment: The `p` in `\cs_new_protected:Npn` means we must write the *parameter text* after the function name (e.g., `#1#2` in the second approach), just as with `\def`. It's simple work and makes reading the definition by TeX slightly faster than with `\cs_new_protected:Nn`. The `protected` makes it so that if the function your are defining (such as `\Qoptions_question_header:n` or `\Qoptions_question_header:nn` here) is used in an expansion-only context (e.g., `\edef\x{\Qoptions_question_header:n{...}}` or `\write\somestream{\Qoptions_question_header:n{...}}`,

Comment: or inside `x` and `e`-type arguments in `expl3`), it won't expand. This is useful because `\Qoptions_question_header:n` and `\Qoptions_question_header:nn` contain several “unexpandable macros” that are only useful to expand in a typesetting context (`\textbf` is one of them). In general, you should define macros as `\protected` unless you know they will behave properly in an expansion-only context—this is what `xparse` does with `\NewDocumentCommand` and friends, as opposed to `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` and friends.

Comment: Your comments are as informative as your original answer. I need to clear my mind in order to fully understand what you have written. I highly appreciate your willingness to explain every issue I raised. I hope you don't mind if I come back in the future with more inquiries `:)`.

Comment: In order to really understand the `protected` thing, you probably need to search the site for “fully expandable” and “protected macros”. It's probably too difficult to make it clear in two or three comments (well, depending on what you already know). But if it's too complicated, just always use `protected` until you stumble on a problem which makes you realize that you don't want it. An example where you don't want it is if you define a macro that is used in an `x`-type argument (see below).

Comment: For instance: `\cs_new:Npn \Qoptions_foo:n #1
  { \str_case:nnF {#1} { {A} {output for A} {B} {output for B} } {error} }

\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { Bla \Qoptions_foo:n {A} bla... }`. Here, `\tl_set:Nx` uses `\Qoptions_foo:n` inside `\edef` behind the scenes for the `x`-type argument, and in order for `\Qoptions_foo:n` to expand in this context (inside `\edef`), it must be a non-`\protected` macro.

Comment: Regarding `\protected` macros and the meaning of “fully expandable,” I'd suggest reading [On unprotecting (expanding) \protected macros (or, “the space after command name”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57229/73317) and [Advantages and disadvantages of fully expandable macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66118/73317).

Comment: I modified the answer a bit regarding the `\tl_if_blank:...` test for the label (little simplification noticed by egreg).

Answer (score 1):

When you call `\tl_if_blank:nTF { \l__Qoptions_label_tl }` you always get false, because the argument is not empty.

With your new approach you just do `\tl_use:N \l__Qoptions_label_tl`, because the variable will always contain the desired string: either the initial value or what has been specified with the `label` key.

Using `\IfValueT` is good *only* if you pass a specific argument. With the new approach you test whether the value stored in the `sublabel` variable is empty (which means it hasn't been set). You can test whether if the `sublabel` key has received a value with `\tl_if_blank:V(TF)` (the parentheses mean that you can use `T`, `F` or `TF` and supply the appropriate number of arguments).

```latex
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[xparse]{tcolorbox}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\NewTColorBox{MarksTCBox} { O{} }{
    left skip= 0pt,
    right skip=0pt,
    left=2pt,
    right=2pt,
    capture=hbox,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    nobeforeafter,
    box align = base,
    baseline=4pt,
    #1,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { Qoptions }
  {
    label       .tl_set:N  = \l__Qoptions_label_tl,
    label       .initial:n = Question,
    sublabel    .tl_set:N  = \l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl,
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \Qoptions_question_header:n #1
  {
    \qformat
      {
        % \question appears to create a group, so the options are duly cleared
        % when the question title has been typeset.
        \keys_set:nn { Qoptions } {#1}
        \textbf
          {
            \underline
              {
                \large
                \tl_use:N \l__Qoptions_label_tl
                \c_space_tl
                \thequestion
                \c_space_tl
                \tl_if_blank:VF \l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl
                  { [ \l__Qoptions_sublabel_tl ] \c_space_tl }
                \begin{MarksTCBox}
                    \scan_stop: [\totalpoints\ Marks]
                \end{MarksTCBox}
              }
          }
          \hfill % Otherwise, you'll have an Underfull \hbox for each question.
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \myQFormat } { O{} }
  {
    \Qoptions_question_header:n {#1}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}

    \myQFormat
    \question[15]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
    The output should be ``Question 1 [15 Marks]''

    \myQFormat[label = Part]
    \question[10]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
    The output should be ``Part 2 [10 Marks]''

    \myQFormat[label=Part, sublabel=Subtitle]
    \question[5]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
    The output should be ``Part 3 [Subtitle] [5 Marks]''

    \myQFormat[sublabel=Subtitle]
    \question[10]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
    The output should be ``Question 4 [Subtitle] [10 Marks]''

  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```