Use Acronym result in /IfStrEq
I try to track changes in a LaTex document and implemented something like the \change.
It works by using strike-through and colors. My problem is that I now use the
acronym package and want to track the places where the acronym representation changes
In the example below I have an old text where I used the short version of the acronym
as plain text SA. Now I want to use the acronym command \ac{SA}. This command will expand to either simpel acronym (SA) or the short form SA. I do not know which one
will occur but I only want to track the change if the strings are different.
In the MVE below I use IfStrEq which should expand macros see xstring page. 20. It works for plain strings \change{same}{same}
and for my own command \change{bar}{\foo} (\foo evaluated to bar).
However, for the \ac command from the acronym package it does not work.
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\foo}{bar}

\newcommand{\change}[2]{
    \fullexpandarg
    \IfStrEq{#1}{#2}{%true
        {\color{green}#2}\xspace
    }{%false
        {\color{red}\sout{#1}}\xspace
        {\color{blue}{#2}}\xspace
    }}


\begin{document}
\acrodef{sa}[SA]{simpel acronym}

The first usage of the acronym: \ac{sa}.\\
Here is the second usage of acronym \ac{sa} only producing the short form.\\

Also the third usage produces the short form but the change macro says they
are different \change{SA}{\ac{sa}}.\\

Using the change macro an different string \change{it works}{it DOES Work}.\\
If arguments are plain strings macro works. \change{same}{same}. \\
Using the foo command which returns 'bar' as string works with IfStrEq: \change{bar}{\foo} works

\end{document}



Apparently, \ac is protected and will not expand until printed.  Try \edef\myac{#2}\meaning\myac.

Look lik it \edef\myac{#2}\meaning\myac printed macro:-¿“ac –sa˝ before the \ac case and the expanded version of the foo command macro:-¿bar. I assume that the command is protected for a reason. Can I 'unprotect' it or delay my command until I can get the value of \ac?

Not sure.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57229/on-unprotecting-expanding-protected-macros-or-the-space-after-command-name?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C49.7492
