# \the\year in Roman and \the\month in text

Tags: datetime

I would like to get the month in text e.g., `June` and the year in Roman, e.g. `MMXIV` when I call `\the\month` and `\the\year`

I also would like to avoid using any external package (I found some related questions, but all seem to be based on the `datetime` package):

[\today month as text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112932/today-month-as-text)

[Month Name in Upper case](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83108/month-name-in-upper-case?rq=1)

[How do I "unprotect" an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48825/how-do-i-unprotect-an-argument)

[Change \the\year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185188/change-the-year)

Comment: I assume you're up for a macro pair like `\MONTH` and `\YEAR` that does that?

Comment: @Werner Well, I don't know if a new macro or to `\renew` `\year` and `\month`

Comment: Well, see if my answer provides you with hope... :) If not, I'll delete it.

Comment: I'm asking why you don't want to use a package; just for reinventing the wheel? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg, maybe because I feel there is no need for a whole package for something that looks so simple?  Perhaps I'm mistaken here...

Comment: @MarioS.E. You are. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Could you please write an answer using a package, then? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following minimal example defines `\MONTH` and `\YEAR` that provides the output you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\MONTH}{%
  \ifcase\the\month
  \or January% 1
  \or February% 2
  \or March% 3
  \or April% 4
  \or May% 5
  \or June% 6
  \or July% 7
  \or August% 8
  \or September% 9
  \or October% 10
  \or November% 11
  \or December% 12
  \fi}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\YEAR}{\@Roman{\the\year}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Month: \the\month, \MONTH \par
Year: \the\year, \YEAR

\end{document}
```

Comment: Smooth :D.  Is `\month` always provided in numeric format? Why is so?

Comment: @MarioS.E.: Yes. See section **33.5 Time** in [TeX by Topic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf).

Answer (score 12):

I don't see why reinventing the wheel. `;-)`

The `datetime` package supports several languages and, if one is not supported, the package author will surely be glad to add it. Perhaps also an interface for printing the year in Roman numerals would be useful in the package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Romanyear{\@Roman{\year}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\monthname, \Romanyear

\selectlanguage{italian}

\monthname, \Romanyear

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just remember why I didn't try this one: what I have is a `\gdef\@thesisdate{\the\month \the\year}` in my .sty file.  If I use @Werner's solution, I'd have: `\gdef\@thesisdate{\MONTH \the\year}`, which works just fine for both the pdf document and the hyperref pdf setup later.  If I go like your answer, I get a warning saying that \monthname is not a valid token

Comment: Naturally, the `\newcommand{\Romanyear}{...}` works perfectly :)

Comment: `\@Roman{\number\year}` can be simplified to `\@Roman{\year}`, because `\year` is already a "TeX number".

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I'll never remember that `\@Roman` and the similar commands already do `\number` or `\romannumeral`. Thanks.