# Error with \DeclareRobustCommand, \usepackage{hyperref,xcolor} and \usepackage{graphicx}

Tags: macros, errors

In order to tie capital letters with a capital hyphen, I created a command

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\capitalhyphen}{\raisebox{0.24ex}{\resizebox{0.4em}{\height}{-}}\kern-0.07em}
```

which uses `graphicx` package. I'd like to use this command in `\chapter` and similar 'moving arguments'. This code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\capitalhyphen}{\raisebox{0.24ex}{\resizebox{0.4em}{\height}{-}}\kern-0.07em}
\begin{document}
\chapter{ФІЗИКО\capitalhyphen МАТЕМАТИЧНИЙ}
\end{document}
```

works fine and does the job. However, adding

```
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref,xcolor}
\hypersetup{citebordercolor=green,linkbordercolor=white}
```

to the preamble, results in an error. Ho to fix it?

**UPDATE:** I figured out that if we add `bookmarks=false` option the problem disappears. Is there any chance to use this `\DeclareRobustCommand` and still have bookmarks??

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand` or your definition but `\protect\capitalhyphen` when used in a moving argument. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands) for a technical description of the problem and [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43127/error-with-newcommand-and-section) for a similar problem.

Comment: @egreg, doesn't work either

Comment: Sorry, but a minimal (non) working example is needed.

Comment: You will need to delete your toc file after making your command robust and let latex write a new clean one. The old one will be corrupted.

Comment: I get the error message when I try to put \DeclareRobustCommand{}, not even when I use this in the \chapter{}. And yes, I deleted toc file

Comment: Please edit your question to include a complete small document starting \documentclass and ending \end{document} that shows the problem.

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\capitalhyphen}{...}` is the correct way; sorry if my comment has been misleading. Then you don't have to use `\protect` in front of `\capitalhyphen`

Comment: Also, you need the `graphicx` package to also be included, since you're using `\resizebox`.

Comment: See the log file, please

Comment: If I remove `\protect` (that doesn't belong there), I get no error. It's probably a problem of encoding; retype the chapter title, but before running `pdflatex` for the first time, remove the `.aux` and `.toc` files.

Comment: I've tried this, unfortunately this doesn't help either. By the way, when I try to compile the document with www.sharelatex.com, I get the same error message ! undefind control sequence \height leading text: bla-bla-bla

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the bookmarks macro `\capitalhyphen` can be redefined using `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`:

```
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\capitalhyphen{-}%
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the command in the preamble and also load `graphicx` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\capitalhyphen}{\raisebox{0.24ex}{\resizebox{0.4em}{\height}{-}}\kern-0.07em}
\begin{document}

\chapter{ФІЗИКО\capitalhyphen МАТЕМАТИЧНИЙ}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package
 english.ldf    2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system
ukraineb.ldf    2008/03/21 v1.1l Ukrainian support from the babel system
  t2aenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  t2acmr.fd    2001/08/11 v1.0a Computer Modern Cyrillic font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

---

If you add

```
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref,xcolor}
\hypersetup{citebordercolor=green,linkbordercolor=white}
```

You get an error that `\height` is undefined. `hyperref` needs to do a lot of normalising of characters to meet the restricted encoding allowed in pdf bookmarks. It apparently disables the latex protection mechanism to do that.

You can add `\let\height\relax` then you get no error but the bookmark list isn't right.  however

```
\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}
\hypersetup{citebordercolor=green,linkbordercolor=white}
```

seems to work

Comment: I forgot to include it in the minimal example, but I DO HAVE IT in my main document. Please, see the log file I've added to my question. It's odd, but when I use the usual hyphen inside \chapter{} in my main document I have no error, the error pops up when I try to use \captialhyphen, and this error has to do with inputenc (see the log)...

Comment: @Physicsworks The error is completely unrelated to `\capitalhyphen`.

Comment: @Physicsworks The code in my answer runs without error and produces the result shown.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, this is what I'd like to get. Unfortunately, what I get is the error message above =( : ! Undefined control sequence. Strangely, in the minimal working example I get ANOTHER error (! inputenc). Just great...

Comment: The inputenc error is unrelated (had you asked that this one would not have been closed) so you may want to ask a new question (or edit the question title of this one) about that, add \listfilesto your preaamble, you may have an old version, I added my output to the answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I've edited the question.

Comment: Which just shows why we always ask for full working examples in questions:-)(I'll update my answer to match(

Comment: @David, Yeah =) In this case I couldn't insert the full document because of its size, and even a preamble is huge, so just by using a trial and error method (by deleting the portion of the preamble and compile it to see whether it works or not) I finally figured that the problem was not about encoding ...  Anyway, thank you all guys and +1 to everyone who added an answer!